# ADO pipeline triggers, ORing tag conditions

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am building an ADO CI pipeline and trying to trigger one CI pipeline from another using pipeline triggers. Using the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops

[image]

Using yaml, as shown in the snippet above.

However, I want my pipeline to trigger based on OR condition for tags. If the build has tags Production OR Signed, I want the other CI pipeline to kick in.
Is there a way to do that?
All articles I find talk about ANDing the tags conditions. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Update 1:
Tried the below and it dint work. It still triggers the pipeline only when both Signed and Production tags are present.

```
    resources: 
      pipelines: 
      - pipeline: MyCIAlias
        source: Farbrikam-CI 
        trigger: 
        tags: 
        - Production 
      - pipeline: MyCIAlias 
        source: Farbrikam-CI 
        trigger: 
        tags: 
        - Signed
```

Comment: Add two resource definitions, one for each tag, then add conditional logic where necessary to differentiate between the two pipeline resources.

Comment: I tried the below and it dint not work, The pipeline is still triggered when both 'production' and 'signed' tags are present. Is there anything else I can try?
``` resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: MyCIAlias
    source: Farbrikam-CI
    trigger:
      tags: 
      - Production 
  - pipeline: MyCIAlias
    source: Farbrikam-CI
    trigger:
      tags: 
      - Signed ```

Comment: Update your question with what you've tried and what hasn't worked.

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: Any insights on this? If this possible, as I am still struggling with it.